# How to add a hover element to ggvis bar chart

Tags: r, ggvis

I am trying to create a bar chart in ggvis, where you can hover over its elements and see the number represented by each bar.

```
range <- rep(c("0","1","2", "4"),2)
gender <- rep(c("male", "female"),4)
value <- runif(8)
df <- data.frame(Range = range, Gender = gender, Value = value)
df%>% ggvis(~Range, ~value) %>%
layer_bars(width =.1 ,fill = ~gender)
```

How can I make the elements display the value and the gender when I hover over them? And how can I make the bars show next to each other instead of being stacked?

Comment: @Pascal sorry that meant to say gender. I copy pasted my code and generated the dummy variables. In the original code variable stands for gender.

Comment: I don't think there's "dodging" in ggvis yet, but see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27270619/2461552) for a possible work around.  In terms of adding a tooltip, what didn't work?  Did you try code from the `add_tooltip` help page?

Comment: I needed the tooltip to show the number per factor. Now that I have seen the answer you are linking to, I think I know for sure that ggvis just won't cut it here.